# Qweb Xpath of child node in odoo / openERP?

Tags: xml, xpath, css-selectors, odoo, qweb

Here i want insert a LI item inside existing UL

I tried this,

> XML

```
<ul id="top_menu">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

> XPATH

```
  <xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']/li[1]" position="after">
     <li><a>100</a></li>
  </xpath>
```

I got my new item "100" at last item of `<ul>`. but i need it in after 1st item.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this :- //ul[@id='top_menu']/li[1]/a

Comment: @Jain@ i tried this, but shows an error.

Comment: what error you are encounted?

Comment: Have you tried with following answer? It is advisable to share feedback of any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime in tricky solution, we need to override/replace base id and then rearrange it based on our requirement.

try with this code:

Replace your code

```
<xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']/li[1]" position="after">
    <li><a>100</a></li>
</xpath>
```

with

```
<xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']" position="replace">
    <ul id="top_menu">
        <li><a>1</a></li>
        <li><a>100</a></li>
        <li><a>2</a></li>
        <li><a>3</a></li>
    </ul>
</xpath>
```